# "Every hiker climbed a hill", is there one or multiple hills?

Tags: grammar

This question comes from a quiz but I could not find the correct answer.

[image: Hikers climbing a hill]

Comment: Both are correct.  Least correct is the test that contained this.

Comment: @HotLicks Afaik that test was designed to identify your dialect and country of origin. They basically ask what feels more correct to *you*, not what is grammatically correct.

Comment: @GEdgar Perhaps explain to them why they should do that?

Comment: To provide some context about the quiz, @Jack Aidley was studious enough to find a study that utilized this quiz to gather information about use of the English language. The question appears to be intentionally vague - it is not testing for a CORRECT answer, but rather testing to see WHICH answer a given subject chooses. When correlated with other responses and personal details, this was used to draw conclusions about English language education.

Comment: Every hiker [in the group] climbed a hill. [general activity] versus Every  hiker climbed the hill. [the one in question]. If every hiker climbed a hill, then, all the hikers also climbed a hill.

Comment: I would refuse to answer. *Neither* answer is *more* correct than the other.

Comment: This shows the problem with polling users about their language usage by asking which is "most correct." If they can't determine that one is incorrect -- and I would strongly argue that neither is incorrect -- then the question is meaningless. There is no 'more right" if neither is wrong. Or is that just pedantic semantics? Hmmmmm. I still think it's a bogus poll question.

Comment: @user8356 I don’t think it’s pedantic semantics. If you were to view the question logically, then yes, both answers are equally valid. However, if someone in conversation were to tell me “every hiker climbed a hill,” I would make an interpretation that is more specific than a simple existential qualification for the hill (i.e., I would assume that the hills were separate). The question is trying to identify whether people are inclined to think “a hill => unique hill” or “a hill => the same hill” without any further context - even if they would accept either when presented with more context.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This image comes from a Quiz "Which English?" which people were invited to take as part of a study into language acquisition. While the Quiz purports to be able to identify which local variant of English you speak from your answers, it actually serves dual purpose and forms part of a study into how language acquisition varies with age.

According to the [supplementary materials](https://s3.amazonaws.com/l3atbc-public/pub_pdfs/JK_Hartshorne_JB_Tenenbaum_S_Pinker_2018_Supplementary_Materials.pdf) (see p.58) of [the paper](https://s3.amazonaws.com/l3atbc-public/pub_pdfs/JK_Hartshorne_JB_Tenenbaum_S_Pinker_2018.pdf) for which the Quiz was conducted, the correct answer varies by English region so **there is no universally correct answer to this question**.

Answer (score 14):

There is no way to know. As mentioned in a comment, using the indefinite article "a" does not mean that the hikers could not have climbed the same hill.

"There was an event at the park. Each participant crossed a stream, climbed a hill, and rode a bike 5 kilometers."

There is only one stream and one hill in the park. And of course, there was more than one bike -- each person had his own bike, because, really, what else would make sense? Sometimes, context is all, and language is not math. The sentence is  grammatically and factually correct. However, it's possible that there was one bike and they took turns riding it. That would be something that a scientific paper, legal brief, or other technical documentation would have to clarify. In creative writing, that kind of precision can kill the flow and tone.

Comment: Excellent example, showing that both interpretations are plausible.

Comment: I'd argue that "Each participant crossed the stream, climbed the hill, and rode a bike" is more informative and is preferable to using the indefinite article. I don't see any reason to be ambiguous about it if everyone is indeed crossing the same stream and climbing the same hill. It's not wrong, but good writing shouldn't leave the door open for misinterpretation.

Comment: More amusing interpretation: Each participant was on the same bike _at the same time_.

Comment: @Zack Not unlikely if it was an event for clowns or acrobats.

Comment: @NuclearWang: I'd consider \*"the hill" to be wrong in this context, unless the park has only one hill (or there's some other way for the listener to tell which hill is meant).

Answer (score 13):

The indefinite determiner "a" represents all things in a given category rather than the more specific definite determiner "the". So, if you were to ask me, "Every Hiker climbed a hill" represents a specific group of hikers who climbed non-specific hills and not the same hill. If the sentence said, If every hiker had climbed the hill, it would be only one hill.

Comment: Does the use of "a" preclude the possibility of every hiker climbing the same hill? It seems a bit pedantic but the statement would still be true if every hiker climbed the same hill.

Comment: @Areeb No, it doesn't exclude the possibility that there was only one hill. It also doesn't exclude the possibility that there were no hikers at all!

Comment: @Areeb It's true that "a" can be used to refer to the same non-specific hill, but then I would personally use "every hiker climbed some hill" to convey that "[they all climbed the same hill, but I don't know which one]". This is something that would hopefully become more clear in full context.

Comment: Re: ambiguity: Imo, that's why the question ask about "most correct"

Comment: @Sam.  I think "every hiker climbed some hill" makes it even _less_ likely to mean they all climbed the same hill than "every hiker climbed a hill" does.

Comment: @MontyHarder "Some hill" refers specifically to a single unknown hill; "some hill*s*" would refer specifically to two or more unknown hills. Since "hill" is not used as an uncountable noun, this is not ambiguous in my region (but I can imagine regions where this is ambiguous).

Comment: @Sam I disagree completely.  "Some" indicates a _lack_ of specificity.  "Every hiker was required to carry some form of identification" applies "some" to countable ID cards, but no one would think there was only one ID card for all the hikers.

Comment: @MontyHarder Your example doesn't apply: first, "some" applied to "form", not a single object; second, a hill can be hiked by many people, but ID implies only one owner. A better example would be to differentiate between "my friends all went to a movie" and "my friends all went to some movie" -- where I live, the latter is always interpreted as "I don't know what movie my friends went to, but it was the same one"

Comment: @MontyHarder "a" and "some" both lack specificity, but in this context, "a" does not relay the uniqueness of the hills where "some" modifying a singular countable noun does.

Comment: @sam One form of ID is a driver's license.  Another is a state-issued ID card for non-drivers.  Another is a tribal ID card, etc.  Stating that all hikers had some form of ID does not imply that they all had the _same_ form, and saying they all climbed a hill does not imply it was the same hill. You clearly think "some" conveys specificity, and I do not.  The point of the question was to classify people into different groups, and I think this illustrates nicely that such groups exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93594/discussion-between-monty-harder-and-sam).

Answer (score 3):

This seems quite clear to me. In the first picture, every climber climbed a hill; in the second picture, every climber climbed *the* hill. It is easy to construct counter-examples where the second picture is described as "every climber climbed a hill", but the *default* meaning is represented in the first picture. This is why the question is "Which image is *most* correct?"

Comment: If a particular hill was not previously established, then the correct sentence for the second picture would be "There was a hill that every hiker climbed."

Answer (score 1):

In my native dialect (General American), it’s ambiguous, but I’d assume it probably meant multiple hills. “Each hiker climbed a hill,” makes that presumption even stronger. “Every hiker climbed the [same] hill,” and “Every hiker climbed his [own] hill,” are  both unambiguous.